# How to Upsample Pandas DataFrame using Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a DataFrame like this (don't care about NaN values):

[image]

And I would like to upsample it each 20 milliseconds.

What I did is:

```
df = df.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
df = df.resample('20ms').ffill()
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
sens_encoded = sens_encoded.resample('20ms').ffill()
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

So I tried to convert TIMESTAMP to DateTime, which should be already:

```
df = df.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)   //Added this
df = df.resample('20ms').ffill()
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
TypeError: <class 'tuple'> is not convertible to datetime
```

EDIT:

I think the problem might be that after set_index('TIMESTAMP'), the dataframe looks like this(note the parenthesis in the timestamps values):

[image]

**EDIT2**:

I found out why I was getting those parenthesis in df.
It was because I was creating it assigning column names as list inside square brackets. The correct way to do it is:

```
columns_names = ['D07', 'C10', ...]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_names)
```

<s>df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[columns_names])</s>

Comment: How working `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set first level of `MultiIndex` to columns for remove broken one level `MultiIndex`.

Add parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert non parseable values to `NaT` if necessary, also is possible first converting column, then create `DatetimeIndex` and last `upsample`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)

df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], errors='coerce')
df = df.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample('20ms').ffill()
```

Or:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)

df = df.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')
df = df.resample('20ms').ffill()
```

Comment: nope. It gives `'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro - How working `df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].apply(pd.Timestamp)` ?

Comment: second one gives: `ValueError: NaTType does not support dst`

Comment: third one gives: `TypeError: ("'DataFrame' object is not callable", 'occurred at index (TIMESTAMP,)')`

Comment: please check EDIT in question, might be of help!

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro - I edit answer. If still not working, what is `print (type(df['TIMESTAMP']))` ?

Comment: the type of df['TIMESTAMP'] is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro - It means there are duplicated columns names, double `TIMESTAMP`. Give me a sec for solution.

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro - Check edited answer - duplicated columns names are changed by suffix - `.1`, `.2` - So need `df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP.1'])` fiinally.

Comment: I checked and I don't have duplicate in my columns. Anyway I tried your code but np.where throws error: `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`
`

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro - What return `print (df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])` ?

Comment: this: `MultiIndex(levels=[['C01', 'C02', 'C04', 'C05', 'C07', 'C08', 'C09', 'C10', 'C12', 'C13', 'C14', 'D01', 'D02', 'D03', 'D04', 'D05', 'D07', 'D08', 'D09', 'D10', 'H01', 'M01', 'S09', 'SM1', 'SM3', 'SM4', 'SM5', 'TIMESTAMP', 'TV0']],
           labels=[[]])`

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro - what is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro - Please edited answer, `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)` or `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)` should working in first step.

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro - It is problem with broken MultiIndex - hiererchical index, possible solution is get only first level and assign back. Another solution is use `df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)`, but it depends if exist multiple second levels, check it by  `print (df.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP), inplace=True)
df = df.resample('20ms').ffill()
```

Comment: nope. It gives 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'